# What does a domain object factory look like?

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design, factories

I have a `DataMapperFactory` and I think I am doing it correctly and it makes sense to have one but I have a `DomainObjectFactory` too but it just seems pointless. This is it:

```
namespace libs\factories;
use models as Models;

class DomainObjectFactory {

    public function build($name) {

        $className = 'Models\\' . $name;

        return new className();

    }

}
```

The only advantage I can see of this is that I am keeping the `new` operator from being present all over my code.

There has to be more to a `DomainObjectFactory` than this right?

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can use the factory to **abstract** from specific implementations. If you use the `new <classname>` operator, you instantiate a specific class every time. If you want to interchange this class with another implementation at a later time, you will have to manually change every `new` statement.

The factory pattern allows you to **abstract** from specific classes. A valid minimal use case might be something like this:

```
interface UserInterface {
    public function getName();
}

class UserImplementationA implements UserInterface {
    private $name;
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
}

class UserImplementationB implements UserInterface {
    public function getName() { return "Fritz"; }
}

class UserFactory {
    public function createUser() {
        if (/* some condition */) return new UserImplementationA();
        else                      return new UserImplementationB();
    }
}

$f = new UserFactory();
$u = $f->createUser();   // At this point, you don't really have to care 
                         // whether $u is an UserImplementationA or
                         // UserImplementationB, you can just treat it as
                         // an instance of UserInterface.
```

One use case (of many) when this becomes extremely useful is when working with unit tests. In Test-Driven Development, you often replace dependencies of classes with **mock objects** (objects that implement a certain interface, but don't really do anything). Using the factory pattern, it is quite easy to transparently substitute specific classes with mock classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have started using interfaces a lot lately and beginning to get into unit testing also so I understand what you are on about. One thing though, you have a `UserFactory` with one method in it, do you insist I create a `*Factory` for every domain object (I have a good few) with one method in that factory or will I just have a `DomainObjectFactory` with `buildUser()`, `buildProduct()`, `buildInvoice()` methods in it etc?

Comment: No, I don't insist ;) This is a design issue, so there probably is no definite answer. In my personal opinion, using such a "superfactory" (just for lack of a better word, this is not an "official" term) is valid as long as (1) the logic needed to create the objects is not excessively complex, and (2) there are not too many different domain objects.

Comment: I think I have found the answer I was looking for so, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are there major reasons to use factories:

#### 1. Abstract the creation of object

This is one of the most useful structures in your architecture when it comes to unit testing. Having a factory be responsible for the creation of instance makes easier to introduce mocks when testing.

Also, as added benefit, your is not anymore tightly coupled to the name of the classes that you utilize.

#### 2. Simplify instantiation

Here you have two aspect that you have to consider. First - the ability to instantiate different objects based on some condition - was already quite well described in [helmbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965677/727208) <sub><sup>(+1 for him)</sup></sub>.

The other case is when you are instantiating domain objects, which more complex.
Something like this:

```
$employees = new EmployeeCollection;
$address = new Location;
$class = $type . `Company`;
$company = new $class( $employee, $address );
```

There is quite a lot to do before you can create an instance of `HoldingCompany`. But this whole process can be done withing the factory. Especially if your domain object factory makes a good use of correctly implemented DIC (which is quite rare, btw).

#### 3. Prepare objects before they are released in the application

You should **never** do any computation in the constructor. It make impossible to test that code. Constructors should only contains simple variable assignments.

But this introduces an issue: sometimes you need to do few logical operations, before you can let other code structures to deal with your instantiated object. As beginners we usually do that in the constructor. But where to put it now?

This is where factories come to the rescue.

```
public function create( $name )
{
     $instance = new $name;
     if ( is_callable($instance, false, 'prepare') )
     {
         $instance->prepare();
     }
     return $instance;
}
```

Now, when you use `$factory->create('foobar')`, your object is fully primed to be used.

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you recommend having a different method in the factory for each domain object? So I could do `$domainObjectFactory->build('someObject');` and that method would check if a method exists in the factory called `buildSomeObject()` and if one does execute and return that method?

Comment: No. I would not. Usually you either simple domain objects, with no dependencies, or you are in a situation when you are building complex object graphs. That's when you should be using DIC, to create/retrieve said dependencies. There might be some exception when it is more pragmatic to create one additional method, that create a specific type of domain object, but that is more of an exception then a standard practice

Answer (score 1):

```
public function build($name) {

        $className = 'Models\\' . $name;

        return new $className();
}
```

That would work for you.

Defining object factories is a good practice, when you would like to set some default properties to objects, and also, you will not have to worry in what namespace or directory some class exists.

Example:

```
public function createButton($name){
    require("home/lib/display/Button.php") ;

    $button = new Button($name, "some default param") ;
    $button->visible = true ;
    return $button ;
}
```

You just make default objects so quickly via such factories, besides keeping word `new` away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only started learning namespaces today and left out the extra backslash when typing the question. I am amazed if that is really all there is to a `DomainObjectFactory`. I made that factory ages ago and always thought there was something missing because it is so small. Is the only reason for using this factory to keep the `new` operator from being all over your code?

Comment: So would you say it's better to do it my way with the `build($name)` method and return an empty domain object or have a different method for each domain object in the `DomainObjectFactory` like `buildOrder()`, `buildProduct()` etc?